# JSONException occur while give the review

Tags: android

### **This is my error log.While i am parsing a data that time this error will occur.**

```
    05-03 10:33:27.175: W/System.err(28526): org.json.JSONException: No value for userfeedback
    05-03 10:33:27.175: W/System.err(28526):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
    05-03 10:33:27.175: W/System.err(28526):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:548)
    05-03 10:33:27.175: W/System.err(28526):    at redixbit.restaurant.Review.getdetailforNearMe(Review.java:773)
    05-03 10:33:27.175: W/System.err(28526):    at redixbit.restaurant.Review.access$0(Review.java:742)
    05-03 10:33:27.175: W/System.err(28526):    at redixbit.restaurant.Review$getreviewdetail.doInBackground(Review.java:650)
    05-03 10:33:27.175: W/System.err(28526):    at redixbit.restaurant.Review$getreviewdetail.doInBackground(Review.java:1)
    05-03 10:33:27.185: W/System.err(28526):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    05-03 10:33:27.185: W/System.err(28526):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    05-03 10:33:27.195: W/System.err(28526):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    05-03 10:33:27.195: W/System.err(28526):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    05-03 10:33:27.195: W/System.err(28526):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    05-03 10:33:27.195: W/System.err(28526):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

---

### This is my code of review class.While i m giving review it will give jsonexception can give only one time 2nd time it will give json exception.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class Review extends Activity {
    ListView list_review;
    String[] str = { "abc", "def", "pqr" };
    Float rate = 0.0f;
    Button btn_add;
    RelativeLayout rl_adddialog;
    RelativeLayout rl_userdialog;
    String id;
    ArrayList<Restgetset> rest;
    ArrayList<User> rest1;
    public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "Restaurant";
    Vector<String> bgName;
    EditText edt_nameuser, edt_usermail, edt_comment;
    String username, useremailid, userrate, usercomment;
    RatingBar rb1234;
    String user1, user2, uservalue, updateuname, updateumail;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    View layout12;
    RelativeLayout rl_home, rl_back;
    ImageView img_back;
    String emailpattern;
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    private String Error = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        getActionBar().hide();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_review);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
        // check for Internet status
        if (isInternetPresent) {
            if (getString(R.string.review_banner).equals("yes")) {
                AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
            }else {

                AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            emailpattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
            initialize();

            Intent iv = getIntent();
            id = iv.getStringExtra("id");
            Log.d("id123", "" + id);

            new getreviewdetail().execute();
            initialisedialog();
        } else {
            // Internet connection is not present
            // Ask user to connect to Internet
            RelativeLayout rl_back = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_back);
            if (rl_back == null) {
                Log.d("second", "second");
                RelativeLayout rl_dialoguser = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_infodialog);

                layout12 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        R.layout.connectiondialog, rl_dialoguser, false);

                rl_dialoguser.addView(layout12);
                rl_dialoguser.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                        Review.this, R.anim.popup));
                Button btn_yes = (Button) layout12.findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
                btn_yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    }

    private void initialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        rl_home = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_home);
        rl_back = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_back);
        img_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_back);
        bgName = new Vector<String>();
        rest = new ArrayList<Restgetset>();
        rest1 = new ArrayList<User>();
    }

    public void initialisedialog() {

        btn_add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        btn_add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                layout12 = v;

                list_review.setEnabled(false);
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME,
                        MODE_PRIVATE);

                // check user is created or not
                if (prefs.getString("score", null) != null) {
                    uservalue = prefs.getString("score", null);
                    Log.d("user3", uservalue);

                    if (rl_back == null) {
                        RelativeLayout rl_dialoguser = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_infodialog);
                        layout12 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                                R.layout.giverate, rl_dialoguser, false);
                        rl_dialoguser.addView(layout12);
                        rl_dialoguser.setAlpha(1);
                        img_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_back);
                        img_back.setAlpha(0.8f);
                        // rl_home.setAlpha(0.5f);

                        edt_comment = (EditText) layout12
                                .findViewById(R.id.txt_description);
                        rb1234 = (RatingBar) layout12
                                .findViewById(R.id.rate1234);
                        Button btn_submit = (Button) layout12
                                .findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
                        btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                // rl_adddialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                layout12 = v;
                                list_review.setEnabled(true);
                                // rl_home.setAlpha(1.0f);

                                try {
                                    usercomment = edt_comment.getText()
                                            .toString().replace(" ", "%20");
                                    userrate = String.valueOf(rb1234
                                            .getRating());
                                    if (usercomment.equals(null)) {
                                        usercomment = "";
                                    }
                                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                                    // TODO: handle exception
                                }

                                Log.d("comment", "" + usercomment);
                                Log.d("rate", "" + userrate);

                                new getratedetail().execute();

                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                        Review.this);
                                builder.setMessage(
                                        "Thank you for your feedback")
                                        .setTitle("Thanks..");

                                builder.setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok,
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(
                                                    DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int id) {
                                                dialog.cancel();
                                                new getreviewdetail().execute();
                                            }
                                        });
                                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                                alert.show();
                                View myView = findViewById(R.id.rl_back);
                                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) myView
                                        .getParent();
                                parent.removeView(myView);
                                img_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_back);

                            }
                        });

                        Button btn_cancel = (Button) layout12
                                .findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
                        btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                list_review.setEnabled(true);
                                View myView = findViewById(R.id.rl_back);
                                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) myView
                                        .getParent();
                                parent.removeView(myView);
                                img_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_back);

                            }
                        });

                    }

                } else {

                    if (rl_back == null) {
                        RelativeLayout rl_dialog = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_infodialog);
                        layout12 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                                R.layout.dialog_create, rl_dialog, false);
                        rl_dialog.addView(layout12);

                        img_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_back);
                        img_back.setAlpha(0.8f);
                        rl_dialog.setAlpha(1);

                        edt_nameuser = (EditText) layout12
                                .findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
                        edt_usermail = (EditText) layout12
                                .findViewById(R.id.edt_email12);

                        Button btn_usersubmit = (Button) layout12
                                .findViewById(R.id.btn_submituser);
                        btn_usersubmit
                                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                        username = edt_nameuser.getText()
                                                .toString();

                                        useremailid = edt_usermail.getText()
                                                .toString();

                                        if (useremailid.matches(emailpattern)
                                                && useremailid.length() > 0) {
                                            if (username.equals("")) {
                                                edt_nameuser
                                                        .setError("Enter User Name");
                                            } else {
                                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(
                                                        MY_PREFS_NAME,
                                                        MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                                                editor.putString("username", ""
                                                        + username);
                                                editor.putString("usermailid",
                                                        "" + useremailid);
                                                editor.commit();

                                                new getuserdetail().execute();
                                                View myView = findViewById(R.id.rl_back);
                                                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) myView
                                                        .getParent();
                                                parent.removeView(myView);
                                                img_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_back);

                                                rl_back = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_back);
                                                if (rl_back == null) {
                                                    RelativeLayout rl_dialog = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_infodialog);
                                                    layout12 = getLayoutInflater()
                                                            .inflate(
                                                                    R.layout.giverate,
                                                                    rl_dialog,
                                                                    false);
                                                    rl_dialog.addView(layout12);
                                                    rl_dialog.setAlpha(1);

                                                    img_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_back);
                                                    img_back.setAlpha(0.8f);
                                                }
                                                edt_comment = (EditText) layout12
                                                        .findViewById(R.id.txt_description);
                                                rb1234 = (RatingBar) layout12
                                                        .findViewById(R.id.rate1234);
                                                Button btn_submit = (Button) layout12
                                                        .findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
                                                btn_submit
                                                        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onClick(
                                                                    View v) {
                                                                // TODO
                                                                // Auto-generated
                                                                // method stub

                                                                layout12 = v;

                                                                View myView = findViewById(R.id.rl_back);
                                                                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) myView
                                                                        .getParent();
                                                                parent.removeView(myView);
                                                                img_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_back);

                                                                try {
                                                                    usercomment = edt_comment
                                                                            .getText()
                                                                            .toString()
                                                                            .replace(
                                                                                    " ",
                                                                                    "%20");
                                                                    if (usercomment
                                                                            .equals(null)) {
                                                                        usercomment = "";
                                                                    }
                                                                    userrate = String
                                                                            .valueOf(rb1234
                                                                                    .getRating());
                                                                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                                                                    // TODO:
                                                                    // handle
                                                                    // exception
                                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                                }

                                                                Log.d("comment",
                                                                        ""
                                                                                + usercomment);
                                                                Log.d("rate",
                                                                        ""
                                                                                + userrate);

                                                                new getratedetail()
                                                                        .execute();

                                                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                                                        Review.this);
                                                                builder.setMessage(
                                                                        "Thank you for giving your feedback")
                                                                        .setTitle(
                                                                                "Thanks");

                                                                builder.setNeutralButton(
                                                                        android.R.string.ok,
                                                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                                            @Override
                                                                            public void onClick(
                                                                                    DialogInterface dialog,
                                                                                    int id) {
                                                                                dialog.cancel();

                                                                                new getreviewdetail()
                                                                                        .execute();
                                                                            }
                                                                        });
                                                                AlertDialog alert = builder
                                                                        .create();
                                                                alert.show();

                                                            }

                                                        });

                                                Button btn_cancel = (Button) layout12
                                                        .findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
                                                btn_cancel
                                                        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onClick(
                                                                    View v) {
                                                                // TODO
                                                                // Auto-generated
                                                                // method stub

                                                                View myView = findViewById(R.id.rl_back);
                                                                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) myView
                                                                        .getParent();
                                                                parent.removeView(myView);
                                                                img_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_back);
                                                                // img_back.setAlpha(0.0f);
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                            }

                                        } else {
                                            edt_usermail
                                                    .setError("Enter valid email address");
                                        }

                                    }   
                                });
                        // new changes
                        Button btn_cancel = (Button) layout12
                                .findViewById(R.id.btn_canceluser1);
                        btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                ImageView img_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_back);
                                img_back.setAlpha(0.0f);
                                View myView = findViewById(R.id.rl_back);
                                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) myView
                                        .getParent();
                                parent.removeView(myView);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }

            }

        });

    }

    public class getratedetail extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            URL hp = null;
            try {
                if (uservalue != null) {
                    hp = new URL(getString(R.string.liveurl)
                            + "userfeedback.php?");

                } else {
                    hp = new URL(getString(R.string.liveurl)
                            + "userfeedback.php?res_id=" + id + "&&user_id="
                            + user2 + "&&ratting=" + userrate + "&&comment="
                            + usercomment);

                }

                Log.d("userurl", "" + hp);
                URLConnection hpCon = hp.openConnection();
                hpCon.connect();
                InputStream input = hpCon.getInputStream();
                Log.d("input", "" + input);

                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        input));

                String x = "";
                // x = r.readLine();
                String total = "";

                while (x != null) {
                    total += x;
                    x = r.readLine();
                }
                Log.d("totalid", "" + total);

                JSONObject j = new JSONObject("Massage");

                Log.d("j", "" + j);
                for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject Obj;
                    Obj = j.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i));
                    User temp = new User();
                    temp.setId(Obj.getString("id"));

                    rest1.add(temp);
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        }

    }

    public class getuserdetail extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            URL hp = null;
            try {

                hp = new URL(getString(R.string.liveurl)
                        + "adduser.php?username=" + username + "&&email="
                        + useremailid);


                Log.d("userurl", "" + hp);
                URLConnection hpCon = hp.openConnection();
                hpCon.connect();
                InputStream input = hpCon.getInputStream();
                Log.d("input", "" + input);

                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        input));

                String x = "";
                // x = r.readLine();
                String total = "";

                while (x != null) {
                    total += x;
                    x = r.readLine();
                }
                Log.d("totalid", "" + total);

                JSONArray j = new JSONArray(total);
                Log.d("j", "" + j);
                for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject Obj;
                    Obj = j.getJSONObject(i);
                    User temp = new User();
                    temp.setId(Obj.getString("id"));

                    rest1.add(temp);
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            // if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            // progressDialog.dismiss();
            int start = 0;
            User user = rest1.get(start);
            user2 = user.getId();
            Log.d("user1", "" + user2);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(
                    MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("score", "" + user2);
            editor.commit();
        }

    }

    public class getreviewdetail extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Review.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            getdetailforNearMe();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);


            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                int temp = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < rest.size(); i++) {

                    if (temp == 1) {
                        bgName.add("RED");
                        temp++;
                    } else if (temp == 2) {
                        bgName.add("BLUE");
                        temp++;
                    }
                    if (temp == 3) {
                        bgName.add("GREEN");
                        temp = 1;
                    }
                }
                list_review = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_review);
                LazyAdapter lazy = new LazyAdapter(Review.this, rest);
                list_review.setAdapter(lazy);

                list_review.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        list_review.setEnabled(false);
                        if (rl_back == null) {
                            RelativeLayout rl_dialog = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_infodialog);
                            layout12 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                                    R.layout.reviewclick_dialog, rl_dialog,
                                    false);
                            rl_dialog.addView(layout12);

                            img_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_back);
                            img_back.setAlpha(0.8f);
                            rl_dialog.setAlpha(1);

                            TextView txt_name_comment = (TextView) layout12
                                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_nameuser);
                            txt_name_comment.setText(""
                                    + rest.get(position).getTitle());
                            try {
                                RatingBar rb = (RatingBar) layout12
                                        .findViewById(R.id.rate1234);
                                rb.setRating(Float.parseFloat(rest
                                        .get(position).getRatting()));
                            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                            }

                            TextView txt_comment_desc = (TextView) layout12
                                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_comment_desc);
                            txt_comment_desc.setText(""
                                    + rest.get(position).getAddress());

                            Button btn_ok = (Button) layout12
                                    .findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
                            btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    list_review.setEnabled(true);
                                    ImageView img_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_back);
                                    img_back.setAlpha(0.0f);
                                    View myView = findViewById(R.id.rl_back);
                                    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) myView
                                            .getParent();
                                    parent.removeView(myView);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }


        }

    }

    private void getdetailforNearMe() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        URL hp = null;
        try {
            rest.clear();
            hp = new URL(getString(R.string.liveurl)
                    + "userfeedback.php?value=" + id);

            Log.d("URL", "" + hp);
            URLConnection hpCon = hp.openConnection();
            hpCon.connect();
            InputStream input = hpCon.getInputStream();
            Log.d("input", "" + input);

            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

            String x = "";
            x = r.readLine();
            String total = "";

            while (x != null) {
                total += x;
                x = r.readLine();
            }
            Log.d("URL", "" + total);
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(total);
            JSONArray j = jObject.getJSONArray("userfeedback");

            Log.d("URL1", "" + j);
            for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject Obj = j.getJSONObject(i);

                Restgetset temp = new Restgetset();
                temp.setTitle(Obj.getString("username"));
                temp.setAddress(Obj.getString("comment"));
                temp.setRatting(Obj.getString("ratting"));

                rest.add(temp);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Error = e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Error = e.getMessage();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Error = e.getMessage();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Error = e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Activity activity;
        private ArrayList<Restgetset> data;
        private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        Typeface tf1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(Review.this.getAssets(),
                "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
        String s;

        public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Restgetset> str) {
            activity = a;
            data = str;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi = convertView;

            if (convertView == null) {

                // vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reviewcell, null);
                String temp = bgName.get(position);
                if (temp.equals("RED")) {
                    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reviewcell, null);
                } else if (temp.equals("BLUE")) {
                    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reviewcell1, null);
                } else if (temp.equals("GREEN")) {
                    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reviewcell2, null);
                }
            }

            try {
                String namefirst = data.get(position).getTitle();
                s = namefirst.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();

                TextView txt_first = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txt_first);
                txt_first.setText("" + s);
            } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

            TextView txt_name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_name);
            txt_name.setText(data.get(position).getTitle());
            txt_name.setTypeface(tf1);

            TextView txt_comment = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txt_review);
            txt_comment.setText(data.get(position).getAddress());
            txt_comment.setTypeface(tf1);
            try {
                RatingBar rb = (RatingBar) vi.findViewById(R.id.rate1);
                rb.setRating(Float.parseFloat(data.get(position).getRatting()));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

            return vi;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.review, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you include the JSON that you are trying to parse? As per the logs, it seems that the item with key *userfeedback* may not exist.

Comment: i already passed userfeedbak.

Comment: please give me a solution.

Comment: I can't provide you an accurate solution as I can't see the type of JSON you are parsing, but basing from your logs, what I can suggest if for you to try and change your `JSONArray j = jObject.getJSONArray("userfeedback");` to `JSONArray j = jObject.optJSONArray("userfeedback");`. If it works, great, I'll post it as answer, if it doesn't then we might need some further information (sample of the JSON you are parsing to be specific).

Comment: what you mean by While i m giving review it will give jsonexception can give only one time 2nd time it will give json exception.

Comment: I can give review only once while i am opening my app after that i cant give .